# Redirect according to Radio button after submitting form Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, forms, radio-button, action

> I want to redirect to the online payment page or wallet payment page by selecting the radio button and then clicking Buy Now Button. the form will also submit when I click the buy now button.

```
<form name="game-form" action="submit" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="timeline-wrapper">
        <ul class="StepProgress">
            <li class="StepProgress-item is-done">
                <div class="bold time">STEP 1</div>
                    <div class="bold"><h5>Account Login</h5></div>
                        <div class="form-group account-type">
                            <select class="form-control " style="width: 100%">
                                <option>Default select</option>
                                <option value="">Gmail</option>
                                <option value="">Facebook</option>
                            </select>
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address / Facebook Number</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email/number">
                            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="StepProgress-item is-done">
                        <div class="bold time">Step 2</div>
                        <div class="bold">
                            <h5>Select Recharge</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group recharge-type">
                            @foreach ($games as $row)
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Weekly <sup>BDT {{$row['g1']}}</sup> </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Monthly <sup>BDT {{$row['g2']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">100 Diamond <sup>BDT {{$row['g3']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio4" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio4">200 Diamond <sup>BDT {{$row['g4']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio5" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio5">310 Diamond <sup>BDT {{$row['g5']}}</sup> </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio6" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio6">520 Diamond <sup>BDT {{$row['g6']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio7" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio7">620 Diamond <sup>BDT {{$row['g7']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio8" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio8">830 Diamond <sup>BDT {{$row['g8']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio9" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio9">1060 Diamond <sup>BDT {{$row['g9']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio10" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio10">2180 Diamond <sup>BDT {{$row['g10']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio11" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio11">5600 Diamond <sup>BDT {{$row['g11']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio12" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio12">$0.99 Aidrop <sup>BDT {{$row['g12']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio13" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio13">$1.99 Airdrop <sup>BDT {{$row['g13']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio14" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio14">$2.99 Airdrop  <sup>BDT {{$row['g14']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio15" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio15">Level Up Pass <sup>BDT {{$row['g15']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-inner">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio16" autocomplete="off" checked>
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio16">Bundle Pass <sup>BDT {{$row['g16']}}</sup></label>
                                    </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="StepProgress-item is-done">
                            <div class="bold time">Step 3</div>
                            <div class="bold">
                                <h5>Payment Methods</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group payment-type">
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                                    <i class="fas fa-wallet fa-3x"></i>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">GAMERSHOBBD</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                    <i class="fas fa-money-check-alt fa-3x"></i>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">OtherPayment</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="buy-btn">
                    <button id="top-account-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Buy Now</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is an order page, where people will fillup the form then select the product then select the payment type.
This page will take data to the database then show those data to the next page, which will be wallet payment or online payment. I am new to Laravel. it will very helpful if anyone can give the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with **inline js** as :

```
<select class="form-control " style="width: 100%" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    ...
</select>
```

Or with **JQuery** :

```
$('form select').on('change', function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```